# Python Add Elements of a List (or Set, or whatever Data Type is appropriate)

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition, members

Is there an easy way to add the members of two equally sized `list`s (or `tuple` or whatever data type would work best)?

I have, for example `a` and `b` with 2 elements:

```
a = (0, 10)
b = (0, -10)
```

I want to add them and get as result:

```
result = (0, 0)
```

**NOT `(0, 10, 0, -10)`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in one line in Python:

```
map(sum, zip(A, B))
```

Example:

```
>>> B = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> C = [1, 2, 4, 8]
>>> map(sum, zip(B, C))
[2, 4, 7, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I ended up going with `A = list(map(sum, zip(A, B)))` so that I can iterate through the result as needed.

Comment: @JojoJonas, you don't need to list() to iterate. Just do it.

Comment: When I do `grid = (int(A[0]/500), int(A[1]/500))`, it gives me a **'map' object is not subscriptable error**

Comment: @JojoJonas: you're confusing iteration with accessing by index.  Iteration in Python is the process of going through the elements one by one, and you can do "for x in map(sum, zip(B,C)): print (x)", so iteration works.  Think of a set -- there's no order, so it doesn't make sense to access some_set[4], but you can certainly loop over the contents.

Answer (score 5):

Three options:

```
>>> [a+b for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
>>> map(int.__add__, A, B)
>>> map(sum, zip(A,B))
```

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension, which surprisingly no one else mentioned.  It's not as slick as the map but is a little more robust.

Comment: +1 for int.__add__, I used a lambda for that in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to operate with list of numbers use numpy

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.add(a,b)
array([2, 4])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, just do this

```
map(sum,zip(A,B)
```

or, (actually clearly faster)

```
u=map(lambda a,b:a+b,A,B)
```

Timing examples:

```
A=range(3000)
B=range(3000)
for i in range(15000):
 u=map(lambda a,b:a+b,A,B)   # takes about 7.2 seconds
 # u=map(sum,zip(A,B))       # takes about 11 seconds
 # u=map(int.__add__,A,B) # (Edward Loper) actually also consistently ~0.5 sec slower than lambda
```

Comment: lambda is _overkill_ in this scenario.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I added an example where lambda runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to add the lists:

```
add(array([-1.2, 1.2]), array([1,3]))
```

and the result it:

```
array([-0.2, 4.2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List ANSWER = ()
for index in range(0, len(A))
  ANSWER.append(A[index]+B[index])
```

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why this code wont run: `SyntaxError` for sure and `tuple` does not have `.append`.

Comment: well, the code has just these two mistakes insted of List ANSWER=(), use ANSWER=[]. end the for loop line with a semicolon ":".

Comment: I don't need the code, I was suggesting you to fix it instead of give it a -1.